# Html how to use php variables in html

Tags: php, html, variables

I want to give my buttons an unique id. Lets say my variables name is $unique. How do I implement it?
This is how I think it works :

```
< tr class="button" id="< ?php echo $unique ?>">
```

Is it right?

I've got a second question regarding JS

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var btn = document.querySelectorAll('homeBtn');

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];


[].forEach.call(homeBtn, function(el) {
  el.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
  }
})

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

This is my JS, instead of the 'homeBtn' in var btn and in the forEach I want to replace the homeBtn with my $unique. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes technique is right but remove the space between `<` and `tr`, `<` and `?` & `echo` will end in`;`.

You can run in localhost to check it.

```
<tr class="button" id="<?php echo $unique; ?>">
```

This is how it should look.

Comment: <?php echo $unique; ?> like this?
or <?php echo $unique;?>

Comment: @user1231431 updated my answer. The space before ending `?>` makes no difference.

Comment: For short php expressions like this, use <?= Instead of verbose <?php echo , it's valid php7 syntax/psr.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forgot to put semicolon?

```
< tr class="button" id="<?php echo $unique; ?>">
```